# Can't install anything using snap in ubuntu

Tags: package-management, snap

So, I was trying to install VS Code:

`sudo snap install code --classic`

But I got the following error:

> ```
> error: cannot communicate with server: Post
> http://localhost/v2/snaps/code: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect:
> no such file or directory
> ```

I have no idea what to do, I even deleted and reinstalled snap, but the error still appears...

I did:

`sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd`

and then:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install snapd
```

It doesn't work!

Then I tried:

`sudo service snapd start`

The output:

`snapd: unrecognized service`

If I do:

`snapd services`

Output:

```
snap    2.54.3+20.04.1ubuntu0.2                                                                                         
snapd   unavailable                                                                                                     
series  -
```

With the command:

`systemctl status snapd.service`

I get the following:

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). 
Can't operate.                                          
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

What is the reason this is happening? I'm using wsl2

Comment: Reinstalling `snapd` is rarely required. When you say "It doesn't work" after the `apt install` bit, do you mean that `apt` was unable to install the daemon? That's what it seems like, which would have me think that your VM does not have a working connection to the Internet ... 

Comment: Are you on a virtual machine or wsl?

Comment: Also, please run `systemctl status snapd.service` and update the question with the output. THanks.

Comment: @mchid i am actually using wsl2, sorry for the mistake

Comment: Let me know if this doesn't work and I'll retract the close vote.

Comment: I don't think it does... I already tried the restart of snapd, with the command: `sudo service snapd start` because my system is with sysvinit. If i do `systemctl start snapd.service`  I get                                                                   
> System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.                                          > Failed to connect to bus: Host is down                                                                                  > Failed to talk to init daemon.